# Como disparar uma função jQuery após o usuário parar de digitar?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho que fazer um sistema de pesquisa que mostra se um e-mail já está cadastrado em meu banco de dados, porém não sei como fazer para disparar uma função JS após 3 segundos que o usuário parar de digitar. Até tentei com com `keyup` mais não consegui. Alguém tem alguma base de como eu possa fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É melhor usar `input` em vez de `keyup`, porque o `keyup` vai pegar qualquer tecla digitada, até mesmo <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> ou outra. O `input` vai chamar a função apenas quando algo for digitado no campo.

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
var temporiza;
$("#email").on("input", function(){
   clearTimeout(temporiza);
   temporiza = setTimeout(function(){
      alert("Chama Ajax");
   }, 3000);
});
```

```js
var temporiza;
$("#email").on("input", function(){
   clearTimeout(temporiza);
   temporiza = setTimeout(function(){
      alert("Chama Ajax");
   }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Digite o e-mail" />
```

Comment: vi um problema meio que bobo porem é essencial pra um bom funcionamento, o temporizador deve zerar cada vez que a tecla é pressionada me parece que dessa forma n ão funcionaria assim

Comment: @EstudantePHP Funciona desta forma: cada vez que um caractere é inserido no campo, o temporizador zera. Se achar melhor colocar `keyup`, funciona também, irá pegar qualquer tecla pressionada.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente aqui obrigado :)